# Shopify CLI - Error: cannot load such file --wdm

Tags: ruby, windows, shopify, windows-11

I am getting this error when running the command `shopify theme dev` with Shopify CLI:

```
[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- wdm
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/blob/main/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

Others who have had similar issues in the past suggested running `gem install wdm`, I have done this and had no success. Any help is appreciated!!

- Operating System: Windows 11
- Shopify-CLI: 3.23.0
- Ruby: ruby 3.0.4p208(2022-04-12 revision 3fa771dded) [x64-mingw32]
- Node.js: v18.12.1
- Bundler version 2.3.25 (2022-11-02 commit 6b0b87b1ed)
- git version 2.38.1.windows.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I upgraded to the latest version of Shopify CLI (3.32.1) and the problem got solved.

Use the Command Prompt and just enter the following command to upgrade Shopify CLI:

```
shopify upgrade
```

Comment: I have been updated to the latest version and that didn't work unfortunately